# Google appengine textsearch API is not setting the production namespace

Tags: java, google-app-engine, text-search

I want to retrieve google app engine textsearch data from local machine by setting the namespace and application id to search API. But my code is pulling the local machine data instead of pulling production data. Below is my code. Can anyone please suggest, any mistake in my code.

```
NamespaceManager.set("my_name_space");
SearchServiceConfig config = SearchServiceConfig.newBuilder().setNamespace("my_name_space").build();
AdminSearchServiceFactory searchServiceFactory = new AdminSearchServiceFactory();
final SearchService searchService = searchServiceFactory.getSearchService("my_app_id", config);

GetResponse<Index> response2 = searchService.getIndexes(GetIndexesRequest.newBuilder());
for (Index index : response2)
{
  System.out.println("index name---" + index.getName());
  System.out.println("namespace---" + index.getNamespace());
}
```

From above code I am expecting the existed indexes from production environment, but my code is giving local machine indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try the Remote Client Api or Google Cloud Endpoints, as seems to be useful for the issue you are facing.

Hope this helps.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/remoteapi

[2] https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/